# C++ sum of vector elements using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, iterator

I'm trying the following to get the sum of all the elements in the vector. According to the debugger, the inside of if statement is executed but the result is always 0.

```
double Problem1::recSum(std::vector<double> list) //public
{
    return recSum(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);
}

double Problem1::recSum(std::vector<double>::iterator begin, std::vector<double>::iterator end, double sum) // private
{
    if (begin != end)
    {
        sum += *begin;
        recSum(++begin, end, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I know the vector is filled properly cause I calculate the same sum iteratively before. In case I'm misunderstanding recursion horribly, please provide me with some materials on that matter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to return result of your recursion:

```
double Problem1::recSum(std::vector<double>::iterator begin, std::vector<double>::iterator end, double sum) // private
{
    if (begin != end)
    {
        sum += *begin;
        return recSum(++begin, end, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

As a note, your `recSum` should take `const std::vector<double>& list` to avoid copying your vector, and, obviously, it would be better to iterate elements than use recursion here.
If you want to use recursion, it's probably better to write it this way:

```
double Problem1::recSum(std::vector<double>::iterator begin, std::vector<double>::iterator end) // private
{
    return (begin != end) ? *begin + recSum(begin+1, end) : 0.0;
}
```

One other option is to use [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <numeric>

double Problem1::recSum(const std::vector<double>& list) //public
{
    return std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);
}
```

In your case it's quite obvious, because your `recSum` doesn't have any side effects, and effectively won't make a difference because you do not use its return value. So you always had 0 as a result of your function because first element of your vector was 0. Usually, when you write some algorithm you should try to step trough the code with simple inputs like empty vector, vector with one element, and vector with 2 elements. With 0 and 1 elements it will work, but with 2 elements it will return wrong result. Imagine you had vector of two doubles [0.0, 1.0], on first iteration your sum becomes 0+0.0, and you will recursively call your function with your iterators pointing to the remainder or your sequence: [1.0], second iteration will correctly calculate the sum as 1.0, but then that result isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please vaguely explain the bahaviour of the function without return or give me some clue to find out why I keep making that mistake? I'm only practising recursion here, I know how to iterate through it.

Comment: Actually this is the vector I used `for (double i = 0; i < 15; i+=2) l.push_back(i);` and the result was 0. But there's a very good piece of advice cause now I realized it just returned the first element of the vector. Thanks again.

Comment: @foofaraw with recursive algorithms you should check your base case and verify that adding extra elements works as expected. Something like that. With simple inputs like [0] or [1, 2] it's clear what the result should be like and easy to "step through" the code on a piece of paper.